# Is there a way to clear query string parameters when posting back?

Tags: asp.net, postback, query-string, postbackurl

I have a form that sometimes gets linked to with some query string parameters.  The problem is that when I post back the form, the query string parameter is still there.  It's not really an issue the way I have it setup, but I just don't like it being there, and could see it being a problem if you needed to check for input in a certain order.

Is there a way to clear that query string parameter in an easy, clean way?  I know I could change the PostBackURL on the button, but that doesn't seem too efficient.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, I haven't seen a way to clear it out without a redirect.

Comment: Is there a clean way to do a Response.Redirect() to the page you're currently on?

Comment: Try: Response.Redirect(Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath())

Comment: I know this is really old, but CurrentExecutionFilePath is a property, so you shouldn't have the parentheses at the end. Maybe consider adding your comment to your answer to make it more complete?

Answer (score 7):

I think you've answered your own question. Use the PostBackURL property.

```
<asp:Button PostBackUrl='<%# Request.ServerVariables["URL"] %>' runat="server" Text="Submit" />
```

Or something like

```
foreach (Control ctrl in Page.Controls)
{
    if (ctrl is Button)
    {
        ((Button)ctrl).PostBackUrl = Request.ServerVariables["URL"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

put this at the bottom of your page?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    document.forms[0].action = window.location.pathname;
</script>
```

Comment: Or from code-behind: form1.Action = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);

Answer (score 5):

I was stuck with same issue.

I solved it using the following code block:

```
private void ClearQueryString()
{
    PropertyInfo isreadonly = typeof(System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection).GetProperty("IsReadOnly", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    isreadonly.SetValue(this.Request.QueryString, false, null);
    this.Request.QueryString.Remove("Action");
    this.Request.QueryString.Remove("param1");
    this.Request.QueryString.Remove("paramN");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can in some cases use the `Server.Transfer()` method, which has an overload that allows you to specify whether the querystring and form data should be preserved or not.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you can't rely on Page.IsPostBack for some reason?

If what you're doing is server-side, then it's simple to add a check for IsPostBack in your methods (Page_Load, OnInit, etc) and only processing the querystrings if it's not a post back (i.e. the initial request).

Answer (score 3):

I just came across the same problem and after some hunting on the Web I found this snippet:

```
public void ClearQueryStrings()
{
    string clientCommand = string.Format(
      "document.forms[\"{0}\"].action = \"{1}\";",
         this.Form.Name, Request.Url.Segments[Request.Url.Segments.Length - 1]);

    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "qr", clientCommand, true);
}
```

I call ClearQueryStrings() in my Page_Load after I am done processing the original query string parameters. When the page posts back, the parameters are gone.

[Original article is here.](http://www.nomoreasp.net/2007/10/30/clear-querystrings-in-aspnet/)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Reflection;
```

Use the following code to Clear Query String Parameters.

```
// To clear Query string value
PropertyInfo isreadonly = typeof(System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection).GetProperty("IsReadOnly", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

// make collection editable
isreadonly.SetValue(this.Request.QueryString, false, null);

// remove
this.Request.QueryString.Remove("YourQueryStringParameter");
```

Answer (score 0):

This method is not what you would call a redirect, but it definitely will erase the query string.
Simply add this line to the end of your JavaScript code:

```
window.location.search = "";
```

Or

Add this to the end of your HTML page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.search = "";
</script>
```

Depending on where you insert the code, the timing of erasing the query string will change.

Answer (score 0):

```
PropertyInfo isreadonly = typeof(System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection).GetProperty("IsReadOnly", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    // make collection editable
isreadonly.SetValue(this.Request.QueryString, false, null);
     // remove

this.Request.QueryString.Remove("status");
```

Comment: Isn't this what most of the other answers are already suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

You Can try `Response.Redirect(Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath());`
Its working for me.

Answer (score 0):

When the javascript code is executed it will clean the url

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   var urlWithoutParams = location.protocol + "//" + location.host + location.pathname;

    function clearCurrentURL(){
        window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, urlWithoutParams);
    }
</script>
```